# EF CodeFirst ,how to add custom model to create table?

Tags: ef-code-first

I work on ASP.NET MVC 5.1 and follow [this post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx) to create my own UserProfile table by Table Per Type (TPT) method.

But how do i want to add another model by code first?

For example, i want to add independent table **Country** table and **Currency** table,
I would create the following classes:

**Country.cs**

```
namespace MiaPos.Models
{
    public class Country
    {  
       // Primary key 
        public int CountryID { get; set; } 
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Currency.css

```
namespace MiaPos.Models
{
    public class Currency
    {  
       // Primary key 
        public int CurrencyID { get; set; } 
        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**DataContext.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;

    namespace MiaPos.Models
    {
        public class DataContext : DbContext
        {
            public DbSet<Country> Countries { get; set; }
            public DbSet<Currency> Currencies { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

I place above of them on the **Models** folder,
but how can i recognize by CodeFirst **Add-Migration** command on Nuget Console?
I saw some post say EF will auto generate the migration class if i inherit System.Data.Entity.DbContext class.

Comment: Did you try the Add-migration command and the migration created was empty?

Comment: Yes, but actually i found a solution in dirty way. I search google on whole day, finally i found the main reason is i set AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false; on the configuration, so i have to do on "code-based migration" and i have to create a new migration configuration to avoid conflict with ASP.NET Identity. I am still not sure the solution is correct way, but it works.

Comment: Is the question you are asking, how to generate the tables in the DB from the C# class?